# Why I'm getting exception: InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

The exception is on the code:

```
private void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ActiveDownloadJob adJob = e.UserState as ActiveDownloadJob;
   if (adJob != null && adJob.ProgressBar != null)
   {
      adJob.ProgressBar.Invoke((Action)(() => adJob.ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage));
   }
}
```

On the line:

```
adJob.ProgressBar.Invoke((Action)(() => adJob.ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage));
```

This is the ActiveDownloadJob class in form1:

```
class ActiveDownloadJob
{
            public DownloadImages.DownloadData DownloadData;
            public ProgressBar ProgressBar;
            public WebClient WebClient;

            public ActiveDownloadJob(DownloadImages.DownloadData downloadData, ProgressBar progressBar, WebClient webClient)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.DownloadData = downloadData;
                    this.ProgressBar = progressBar;
                    this.WebClient = webClient;
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Im not sure i need to invoke this line since im not using now a backgroundworker , but im not sure.

This is the full exception message: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
       at WeatherMaps.Form1.DownloadProgressCallback(Object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\Form1.cs:line 290
       at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadProgressChanged(DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Net.WebClient.ReportDownloadProgressChanged(Object arg)
  InnerException:
```

How can i change this line to be without using Invoke or if Invoke is needed how can i fix the line and the exception ?

I know i should handle it in the Form1 Form closing event but how ? What should i do in the form1 form closing event ?

Comment: Did you read the exception message?

Comment: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
It seems that your progress bar is not placed on form, or it is not visible, or something like that. When do you call your download job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you get an exception because `Invoke` needs to post the "Message" to "Message loop" but `Handle` has not been created.

Use `InvokeRequired` to see whether you need an `Invoke`, this will return false when Handle is not created yet so invoke it directly.

```
var method = (Action)(() => adJob.ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage);
if(adJob.ProgressBar.InvokeRequired)
    adJob.ProgressBar.Invoke(method);
else
    method();
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you're trying to modify the progress bar before it has a Window Handle. One way to solve it would be:

```
if (adJob.ProgressBar.Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    adJob.ProgressBar.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        adJob.ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage));
}
```

This is likely caused by the fact that you're invoking this method before the `Form` is actually shown.

Comment: Michael i tried it removed for the test the old code and added yours and im getting exception on the line: if (adJob.ProgressBar.Handle != IntPtr.Zero) ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object it happen when the program is working the progressBars are working and i close the program on the X RED button on the top right corner. I didnt add anything to the form1 form closing event.

Comment: @DoronMuzar, you need to stop the thread before closing the program. You can do that by hooking up to the `Closing` event.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
MethodInvoker mi = () => adJob.ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
if(InvokeRequired) BeginInvoke(mi);
else mi();
```